# How to get Silverlight to display an error when an internal server error gets thrown

Tags: silverlight, exception

In my silverlight application, I want an error to be thrown that is visible to the user when an exception is thrown. Instead, the application just hangs and the silverlight loading bar never goes away, giving no indication that something when wrong to the user. How do I capture server side errors in silverlight in order to display them on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to display the server errors on UI,

> try
>
> ```
>         {
>             Client.ViewWorkActionByAccountCompleted += (a, ae) =>
>
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     if (ae.Error == null)
>                     {
>                         if (ae.Result.Count > 0)
>                         {
>                             (fill your data)
>                         }
>                     }
>                     else
>                         Msgbox.Show(ae.Error.Message);
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>
>                     Msgbox.Show(ex.Message);
>                 }
>                 finally
>                 {
>
>                     Client.CloseAsync();
>                 }
>             };
>             Client.ViewWorkActionByAccountAsync();
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>            Msgbox.Show(ex.Message);
>         }
> ```
>
> You can build your own message box